# multiprocessing_generator modules triggers a permission error

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, generator

I'm found the module [multiprocessing_generator](https://github.com/wetneb/multiprocessing_generator).
I tried that module with the code below :

```
from multiprocessing_generator import ParallelGenerator

def my_generator():
    yield (x*x for x in range(200))

with ParallelGenerator(my_generator(), max_lookahead=100) as g:
    for elem in g:
        print(elem)
```

Here is the error I got (I ran my code in the console, the python file is in my desktop) :

> C:\Users\crd\Desktop>python test.py Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 69, in 
>       with ParallelGenerator(my_generator(), max_lookahead=100) as g:   File
>   "C:\Users\crd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\multiprocessing_generator__init__.py",
>   line 62, in **enter**
>       self.process.start()   File "C:\Users\crd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py",
>   line 112, in start
>       self._popen = self._Popen(self)   File "C:\Users\crd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py",
>   line 223, in _Popen
>       return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)   File
>   "C:\Users\crd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py",
>   line 322, in _Popen
>       return Popen(process_obj)   File "C:\Users\crd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py",
>   line 65, in **init**
>       reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)   File "C:\Users\crd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py",
>   line 60, in dump
>       ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj) AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'ParallelGenerator.**init**..wrapped'
>
> C:\Users\crd\Desktop>Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in    File
>   "C:\Users\crd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py",
>   line 99, in spawn_main
>       new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)   File
>   "C:\Users\crd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py",
>   line 87, in steal_handle
>       _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE) PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé

I cleaned up the code from the multiprocessing_generator module (I deleted every try/exeption, I converted the context-manager into a basic function). But with the code below I got the same error :

```
from queue import Empty

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def ParallelGeneratorLight():
    queue = Queue()

    def wrapped():
        for item in (x*x for x in range(200)):
            queue.put(item)

    process = Process(target=wrapped)

    process.start()
    queue.get()

print(ParallelGeneratorLight())
```

What is wrong with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiprocessing_generator` relies on the multiprocessing module using the `'fork'` start method, because it assumes that the `wrapped` nested function (defined in `ParallelGenerator`'s `__init__`) can be passed as the `target` of a `multiprocessing.Process` object. On a `fork`ing based platform, this is fine; the child process inherits the complete state of the parent (with a few small exceptions like threads), so it has equal access to the `wrapped` nested function (it inherited an exact copy after all).

Problem is, on Windows, the only available start method is `'spawn'`, which requires the `target` (and all arguments) to be `pickle`able (it `pickle`s them, sends them to the child over IPC, and reconstructs them there), and nested functions are never `pickle`able (`pickle`ing a function involves pickling its qualified name to be imported and used on the other side, and the qualified name of a nested function involves unimportable components, in this case, `pickle`ing `ParallelGenerator.__init__.<locals>.wrapped` fails because `<locals>` is clearly not an importable name).

Basically, `multiprocessing_generator` only works on UNIX-like systems, and only if you're using the default start method (`'fork'`); if you [called `set_start_method`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method) with some other value (`'forkserver'` or `'spawn'`), `multiprocessing_generator` can't be made to work.

While this is a bug, it's not a particularly critical bug in most cases; there is very little benefit to the module if the generator must have its values pickled, because most such generators either aren't `pickle`able themselves (e.g. most file-like objects) or `pickle`ing them involves running them to completion (in which case you've lost all your parallelism).

Sorry, but the simple answer here is: **Don't use `multiprocessing_generator` on Windows.**

That said, if your generator is I/O-bound, you *might* be able to benefit from the module by importing it, then immediately monkey-patching it to replace all `multiprocessing` components it relies on with their equivalent `multiprocessing.dummy` names (which are backed by threads, and don't rely on pickling), e.g.

```
from multiprocessing_generator import ParallelGenerator
import multiprocessing.dummy, multiprocessing_generator

# Monkey-patch to use threads
multiprocessing_generator.Process = multiprocessing.dummy.Process
multiprocessing_generator.Queue = multiprocessing.dummy.Queue
```

To be clear, I have not tested this; no warranties are expressed or implied as to whether this will work. It will also be completely pointless if the generator is CPU-bound, at least on the CPython reference interpreter, since CPU-bound generators will hold [the GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/) while running, preventing the main thread from performing work, so you may as well have iterated directly.